# Can't connect to websocket after switching to secured protocol

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, networking, websocket

I have built a web application with NodeJS/Express as the backend. The frontent connects using the websocket protocol. Everything works fine.

Now, I'm switching to the wss:// protocol, which, to my knowledge and according to [this blog post](https://timonweb.com/javascript/running-expressjs-server-over-https/), should be as simple as

Generate self-signed certificate:

```sh
openssl req -nodes -new -x509 -keyout certificate.key -out certificate.cert
```

Backend:

```js
// old
// import * as http from 'http';
// new
import * as https from 'https';

// ...

// old
// const server = http.createServer(app);
// new
const server = https.createServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync('certificate.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('certificate.cert'),
}, app);

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });

// ...
```

Frontend (Angular with RxJS):

```js
// old
// private readonly backend$$ = webSocket<UpdateData<any>>('ws://localhost:8999');
// new
private readonly backend$$ = webSocket<UpdateData<any>>('wss://localhost:8999');
```

However, having made these changes, my Frontend is no longer able to connect to the websocket.

I get the following error (which I'm not able to fully copy from the console for some reason):
[image]

I need to know what the problem here is / could be, or any pointers as to what to check to figure it out.

Comment: Could it be that your server isn't listening to any port? In your copied code there's no `server.listen(PORT)`...

Comment: That happens at the end of the file, just like before

Comment: What do you see when you visit http://localhost:8999 and/or https://localhost:8999 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related to the self-signed certificate, which browsers (at least Firefox, Chrome and Edge) silently disallow in this case.

I could circumvent this by visiting `https://localhost:8999` directly, which displayed the well-known invalid certificate warning message. By clicking past that, the certificate is added as an exception (at least temporarily), and visiting my actual Angular application now also leads to a successful connection to the websocket.

[Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/644248/246458) is a description for how to add self-signed certificates permanently in Firefox. I expect other Browsers to work similarly.