# "WebSocket connection to 'wss://mydomain.com:8080/' failed:" with no extra details

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I am trying to host a websocket using node.js and it seems to host fine, but I cannot connect to it externally because I just get the error in the title. The : after failed suggests there should be extra details and similar questions here prove that, but I'm not getting anything after the colon making this very difficult to debug. I have tried in multiple browsers and I get the same error so it's not my browser causing this. My best guess would be that my cerificates aren't working, but they're the same certificates I use for the rest of my websites and they work fine for them so not too sure.

This is my server-side (node.js) code:

```
const server = require('https').createServer({
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem'),
    key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem')
});

const websocket = new (require('ws').Server)({server});
websocket.on('connection', (client, request) => {
    console.log("New connection from "+request.socket.remoteAddress);
});
```

And my client-side (Javascript) code is just

```
new WebSocket("wss://mydomain.com:8080").onmessage = (event) => {
    console.log(event.data);
};
```

I have tried making my node.js server listen to port 8080 but that made no difference. I have also tried different URLs on the client side (such as without the protocol, without the port, using my ip) but as I would expect, those don't work either.

Comment: On the client side, add also `onopen` and `onerror` handlers to get more information. Is there an access log on the server? Is there a `listen` command on the server side?

Comment: Are those self-signed certificates?  [See post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70184523/cant-connect-to-websocket-after-switching-to-secured-protocol) from @NoBullsh1t

Comment: @Nechoj Probably should have mentioned this in the OP, but I have tried onopen and it was not called and I have tried onerror and an error was created but I couldn’t find any more information in the event. I have apache access logs, so I’ll check them when I’m back on my computer. And as said in the post, I have tried with listen but it made no difference, sadly.

Comment: @UsuallyConfused I believe they’re signed by Let’s Encrypt or Certbot, though I’m honestly not entirely sure how TLS/SSL certificates work. As said in the post, I use these same certificates for the rest of my website which they work for, so unless the certificates only support HTTPS for whatever reason I don’t think this is the issue

Comment: Did you specifically try `.listen(8080)`? Just the port without domain etc.?

Comment: @Nechoj Yes, am I supposed to add anything else?

Comment: No listen port is fine. Did you also try setting up the server according to `https://github.com/websockets/ws`?

Comment: @Nechoj What do you mean? I assumed you were meaning there was things in my Apache config or something I needed to change that was shown on that README, but all I see is installation, documentation and usage examples. I have referred to the usage examples for my code, if that's what you mean

Comment: @Nechoj I have also now checked my Apache access logs and I don't see anything related to node.js (e.g: port 8080 or protocol wss) so I'm assuming that means the issue isn't that the traffic is going to that instead of node.js

Comment: Just realised I forgot to include the error shown in Firefox in the OP but I was meaning to. In Firefox, I get the error `Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://mydomain.com:8080/.` instead

Comment: Another try would be `const server = require('https').createServer({... as before...}); server.listen(8080);` without the wss server. Then serve a simple html file, and access `https://example.com:8080/` to check the certificate chain using a browser.

Comment: @Nechoj That's a fair point. I tried already without SSL and it worked, but haven't tried with https yet. http:// 1.2.3.4:8080/ shows ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE, https:// 1.2.3.4:8080/ shows NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID, http:// example.com:8080/ redirects to https:// example.com/ (Apache) and https:// example.com:8080 redirects to ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR. I'm imagining I only needed to test that last one, but thought I'd check all just to make sure haha

Comment: I can't answer my own question because my previous answers to questions didn't get upvoted but I found the fix! Turns out browsers don't accept the port 8080 for HTTPS/WSS because it is intended for HTTP/WS. You usually use 443 but that was already being used by my main website, but 8443 worked.